# Apply void function on array

Tags: swift, quicksort

I am learning swift right now and wanted to write a quicksort algorithm for [Int]

```
func swap(array:[Int], x:Int, y:Int)->[Int] {  //swap elements in array
    var result:[Int] = array
    result[y] = array[x]
    result[x] = array[y]
    return result
}

func split(array:[Int], u:Int, o:Int , p:Int)->Int {  //where the sorting happens
    let pivot:Int = array[p]
    swap(array: array, x: p, y: o)
    var pn:Int = u

    for j in u...o {
        if(array[j] <= pivot) {
        swap(array: array, x: pn, y: j)
        pn = pn+1
        }
    }
    swap(array: array, x: pn, y: o);
    return pn;
}

func quickSortR(array:[Int],u:Int ,o:Int) {  //recursive call
    if(u < o){
        let p:Int = o
        let pn:Int = split(array: array, u: u, o: o, p: p)
        quickSortR(array: array,u: u,o: pn-1)
        quickSortR(array: array,u: pn+1,o: o)
    }
}

func quickSort(array:[Int]) {  //initial call
    quickSortR(array: array, u: 0, o: array.count-1)
}
```

**My problem is** that I don't know how to apply this implementation on an array.

For example if I got the array `a:[Int] = [3,1,2]`.
I can't check if the implementation is working by `print(quickSort(a))`, because the return type of `quickSort` is `void`.
Of course I can't apply `quickSort` on that array like `a.quickSort(a)`

I really don't want to change my implementation of the algorithm by much if it isn't the cause of that problem (e.g. just the signature or return type)

Comment: You may want to read about functions with “in-out parameters” ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just improve your syntax:

```
func swap(array: inout [Int], x:Int, y:Int) {  //swap elements in array
    let temp = array[x]
    array[x] = array[y]
    array[y] = temp
}

func split(array: inout [Int], u:Int, o:Int , p:Int) -> Int {  //where the sorting happens
    print(ar, u , o , p)
    let pivot:Int = array[p]
    swap(array: &array, x: p, y: o)
    var pn:Int = u

    for j in u..<o {
        if(array[j] <= pivot) {
            swap(array: &array, x: pn, y: j)
            pn = pn+1
        }
    }
    swap(array: &array, x: pn, y: o);
    return pn;
}

func quickSortR(array: inout [Int],u:Int ,o:Int) {  //recursive call

    if(u < o){
        let p:Int = o
        let pn:Int = split(array: &array, u: u, o: o, p: p)

        quickSortR(array: &array,u: u,o: pn-1)
        quickSortR(array: &array,u: pn+1,o: o)
    }
}

func quickSort(array: inout [Int]) {  //initial call
    quickSortR(array: &array, u: 0, o: array.count-1)
}
```

If you use `func swap(array: [Int])` `array` is immutable inside the method. It just copies. Using `inout` resolves this problem.

To check the code use somethink like this:

```
var ar = [1]
quickSort(array: &ar)
print(ar)
```

Comment: How can I check now if the implementation is correct?

Comment: I didn't understand you

Comment: @IPiiro if you need an example, I wrote it

Comment: Just tested it the way you wrote it but it didn't work (the array keep unchanged), so is my algorithm wrong?
In Java I used the same kind of implementation and it worked

Comment: @IPiiro I just change your code to be executed. But I didn't check the logic. I'll try to do it so

Comment: Ofc, it doesn't work, even `swap` doesn't swap anything, just creates new array with swapped elements. Just adding `inout` to arguments is not enough.

Comment: @IPiiro I've change `swap` method and changed `for j in u...o {` into `for j in u..<o {` to prevent fatal error.The algorithm doens't work properly but you can try to improve it.